# Make Photos Non-Pixelatedin Photoshop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, photoshop

I am one day new to photoshop and can not seem to find how to do this... I have a div that is `col-lg-2` and I have an image that I am placing in that div. What is the best way to make an image not become pixelated/dis-proportional when I begin to shrink the size of the screen down. I am using bootstrap, so I would like for it to look the same on a 27 inch screen as it would on an iPhone.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to achieve this? I know it will have to do with the quality of the photo, I don't expect to be able to all of this with CSS. The resolution of my original photo is `640x425`.

**My markup**

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 newClass">
        <div class="module">
            <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="Images/myimage-image.jpg"/>
            <header>
                <h1 style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">Test
                </h1>
                <h2 style="font-size: 13px; text-align: center;">This is some sub-text

                </h2>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .newClass {
        /*background-color: lightgray;*/
        padding: 0px !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }

.module {
        /*background-color: #abc;*/
        background-attachment: fixed;
        /*width: 400px;*/
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        .module > header {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 10px;
            background: inherit;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            .module > header::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: -20px;
                left: 0;
                width: 200%;
                height: 200%;
                background: inherit;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
                filter: blur(4px);
            }

            .module > header::after {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            }

            .module > header > h1 {
                margin: 0;
                color: white;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .module > header > h2 {
                margin: 0;
                color: white;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }
```

**Image**

[image]

Comment: Can we see the image, if it is simple like a logo, it would be possible to vectorize it. If it is more complicated like a photo then you would have to just make sure you never scale it up for any device and that the proportions always remain the same.

Comment: I added an image to my question

Comment: Well, why don't you just make the image a constant size on all devices, by setting the size in pixels. Otherwise it just will pixelate, or you need to use a higher resolution image.

Comment: How can I make it a constant size on all devices?

Comment: You'll have to specify the size in pixels.

Comment: With inline styling?

Comment: Yeah or in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has `.img-resonsive` class available that you can add to your `<img>` tag. This will apply some default CSS rules that allow the image to scale down to smaller screen sizes.

More details on responsive images are here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Generally, moving from a large screen size to a small screen size will not negatively affect image quality. Modern browsers use bicubic downsampling in their scaling algorithms, which is comparable to how Photoshop downsamples images in the application.